# $L^{\infty}$ norm of Integral-Differntial equation's solution

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, integral-operators

Let $\phi(t,z)\in C^{1,2}$ is a function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^D$
, $\rho_{i,j}$ and $\mu_i$ be vector-valued functions and consider the non-linear PDE
$$
\partial_t\Phi(t,z) - \phi(0,z) - \sum_i \mu_i \partial_{z_i}\Phi(t,z)
- 
\frac{\sum_{i,j} \rho_{i,j}\partial_{z_i}\Phi(t,z)\partial_{z_j}\Phi(t,z)
}{2}
= 
\frac{\sum_{i,j} \rho_{i,j}\partial_{z_i,z_j}^2\Phi(t,z)
}{2}
$$
where $\Phi(t,z)\triangleq \int_0^t \phi(s,z)\,ds$.

If $\mu_i$ and $\rho_{i,j}$ are given is it possible to solve the given PDE for $\Phi$?  It not can we calculate or at-least estimate the $L^{\infty}$ norm of $\phi$?

---

*Potential Extra Assumption:*  If need be I may be able to assume (but would prefer not to) that the term on the Right-hand-side is 0.

Comment: You might want to explain what $\partial_x\Phi(t,z)$ is.

Comment: $\partial_t\Phi(t,z)$ is the partial derivative with respect to $t$.

Comment: Pick $\phi(0,z)$ arbitrarily. Once you have done so, your equation becomes a semilinear parabolic equation for $\Phi$. There is plenty of literature on such equations.

Comment: Hmm I actually do know $\phi(0,z)$ can you point me to a reference which gives explicit solutions to this type of PDE?

Comment: Explicit solutions are a bit much to ask for, expect maybe for special choices of the coefficient functions. What I said there is plenty of literature, I meant existence, uniqueness, numerical approximation etc. etc.

Comment: That's alright existence and uniqueness are plenty important for my purposes.  What type of special choices of coefficient functions besides maybe constant ones would give explicit solutions?  Also does this still hold for infinite sums?